# Error: function not defined

Tags: compiler-errors

I am new to Java and am tasked with setting up two classes. One is Person which I have done and compiles without an error. The second is Teacher which adds one variable called subject.  When I try to compile my Teacher class I get Teacher.java:3:error:cannot find symbol and when I go to tools and use Evaluate Line it gives me error(1): function not defined message.

This is my code for the Person Class:

package School;

```
public abstract class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public Person() {
  }
  public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
  }
  public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  public String getFullName() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
}
```

And this is the code for the Teacher class where I am getting the compile error:

```
package School;

public class Teacher extends Person {
/*error(1): function not defined */
    private String subject;

    public Teacher() { 
    }
    public Teacher(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
    }
    public Teacher(String firstName,String lastName, String subject) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        setSubject(subject);
    }

    public String getSubject() { return subject; }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return getFullName() + "Roger" + "Sakowski " + "teaches "+ subject + "English ";
    }
}
```

I have searched the internet and my books I have and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are the two classes in the same package?  Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Yes I can't attach a print screen to show you the setup. I am using Crimson Editor.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the -d option when compiling programs with `package` statements. In other words, you must compile as follows in the directory where you have the two files:

```
javac -d {PUT THE PATH TO THE FOLDER THAT HAS THE FILES HERE, WITHOUT THE BRACKETS} Person.java
javac -d {PUT THE PATH TO THE FOLDER THAT HAS THE FILES HERE, WITHOUT THE BRACKETS} Teacher.java
```

This way the compiler will be able to find the `Person` class. A folder with the given package name (`School`, in this case) will be created. This folder will have the compiled .class files.

Comment: I am using Crimson Editor.  This is what I get when I try to compile either way:

Comment: I am using Crimson Editor.  When I try to compile using the package commands above I get an error that says                                            javac: not a directory: Person.java                                                          Usage: javac <options> <source Files>  If I use the javac Person.java it complies but when I run javac Teacher.java I get the error I noted above.

Comment: I just made a correction to my answer, so that it works for both, Linux and Windows. Replace the dot with the path to the folder in which you have the files.